# Eliminate ambiguity of grammar in antlr

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I am writing a parser. I have a production which is left-recursive `a: a op a` 
so I fix it in this way:
`ab :   () (op ab)*;`
where `op : + | - | / | *`
now I think this is ambiguous,for example for some statement like x+y*z . How can I
eliminate this ambiguity؟

Comment: I do not know, I use one of the options of antlr to remove left recursion `Remove left_recursion` and It is automatically convert to this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ANTLR 3, precedence is implicit in the multiple rule invocations done for an expression. There are plenty of examples of how to build recursive descent expression parsers on the web.

```
expr : primary (op primary)* ;
```

is not ambiguous at all, by the way.

ANTLR 4 allows you to specify left recursive expression rules and implicitly defines a precedence by the order of the alternatives, assuming there's an ambiguity. For example here's a typical rule:

```
expr : expr '*' expr
     | expr '+' expr
     | INT
     ;
```

Comment: I do not know what you mean. my problem is that I have two parse tree for some expression like x+y*z. I think this grammer you have written does not solve this problem. does it?

Comment: Yes, antlr adds preds and rewrites expr to be non-left-recursive. See http://antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf